# Date range query with Lucene 7

Tags: java, lucene, range-query

In the old Lucene version, building date range query was easy:

```
query = NumericRangeQuery.newLongRange(name, startDate(null if not), endDate(null if not), includeStart, includeEnd);
```

I switched to Lucene 7 (lucene-core 7.3.1) and I cannot find a corresponding query type that can accept my date as a long(date.getTime())  :(

Can anyone help? I tried TermRangeQuery but its only taking a string as a constructor argument.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Lucene 7, support for legacy numerics was [removed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-7850?attachmentSortBy=fileName), with the intention that you should start using Point types, which were [introduced](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6852) in Lucene 6.

This means, that right now intended use of it should be something like [this](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/IntPoint.html#newRangeQuery-java.lang.String-int-int-):

```
IntPoint.newRangeQuery(String field, int lowerValue, int upperValue)
```

Comment: thanks, this is what I needed. I am finally using               
      LongPoint.newRangeQuery(nam, Long.MIN_VALUE, Math.addExact(value, -1));